# Angular $http - How to access JSON result values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a `$http` request which returns an object of a user.

```
$scope.profile = $http.get('api/users/' + $stateParams.userId).success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

How do i actually assign for example a user.username to `$scope.profileUsername`?

Copied from the console...

> ```
>     Object
> __v: 0
> _id: "56a1832a36dc3d0e00c7aa3f"
> aboutme: "<p>Im the Boss.</p>"
> additionalProvidersData: Object
> county: "waterford"
> created: "2016-01-22T01:17:30.863Z"
> displayName: "Chris"
> firstName: "Chris"
> gender: "male"
> imageURL: "/modules/users/client/img/profile/saveme-placeholder.png"
> profileImageURL: "../modules/users/client/img/profile/avatars/2/45.png"
> provider: "local"
> roles: Array[2]
> updated: "2016-02-09T02:55:38.744Z"
> username: "abcdef"
> __proto__: Object
> ```

Comment: you will get asynchronous ajax response inside its success call, so use `$http.get('api/users/' + $stateParams.userId).success(function(data) {
        $scope.profile = data;
    });` instead of assinging ajax call to `$scope.profile`

Comment: Interesting to note if you define a `success` callback and a `then` callback for some reason, they will both get called, success first, then second.  success would get the data object, then would get the response object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$http.get('api/users/' + $stateParams.userId).success(function(data) {
    $scope.profileUsername = data.username;
});
```

The return values of the $http methods are promises, not the data.
This is due to their asynchronous nature and the function you pass as a callback is only executed once the HTTP requests returns, so do anything you want to do with the data, you gotta do it in the callback function.

EDIT:
You could also do it like this

```
$http.get('api/users/' + $stateParams.userId).success(function(data) {
    $scope.profile = data;
});
```

That way you can have all the data in one variable, assuming you need all of it. 
In your templates you can then just access the properties with the dot notation (profile.username).

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
 $http.get('api/users/' + $stateParams.userId).success(function(data) {
            $scope.profile=data;
        });
```

It should be accessible on views like `{{profile.username}}`